# Oracle trigger for date

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CRIMEDATE
    BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE of DATE_CLOSED
    ON CRIME
    for each row
    declare :new.date_closed

BEGIN

   if (:new.date_closed < crime_date) then raise_application_error(-20002, 'Date Closed must be after crime date');
   end if;
END;
```

I am trying to create a trigger that will fire if the date entered for date_closed is before the actual crime date but i keep gettng the following error:

```
    Error at line 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the 
    following: begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier> <a double-quoted 
    -identifier> current cursor delete exists prior The symbol "" was ignored. 0.06 seconds
```

I've been trying for ages to figure it out, can any one help? thanks

Comment: You forgot the `new` when referencing the `crime_date`: `:new.date_closed < :new.crime_date`. But a check constraint would be much more efficient here.

Comment: I've tried that but now i get this error: Error at line 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following: begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete exists prior The symbol "" was ignored. 0.07 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CRIMEDATE
    BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE of DATE_CLOSED
    ON CRIME
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF (:new.date_closed < :new.crime_date)  THEN
      raise_application_error(-20002, 'Date Closed must be after crime date');
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but this gives me the following error: Error at line 2: PL/SQL: Statement ignored 0.05 seconds