# Oracle 10g. Trigger that forbids deletion or updating on the last day of month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table 'Flights' with fields (id NUMBER, departure DATE, ...etc).

How to write a TRIGGER that forbids DELETION or UPDATING of those rows that have 'departure' date field = last day of month.

Here's what I've tried to do but I'm getting an error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER forbid_last_day_of_month
    BEFORE DELETE OR UPDATE ON flight
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (departure = last_day(departure))
BEGIN
raise_application_error(-20001, 'No data change allowed on the last day of month!'); 
END;
/
```

But I get this error:

```
ORA-04076: invalid NEW or OLD specification
```

Comment: `WHEN (:NEW.departure..)`

Comment: Another error: ORA-25000: invalid use of bind variable in trigger WHEN clause on trying: WHEN (:NEW.departure = last_day(:NEW.departure))

Comment: use OLD in the second part.

Comment: The same error again. CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER forbid_last_day_of_month
    BEFORE DELETE OR UPDATE ON flight
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (:new.departure = last_day(:old.departure))
BEGIN
raise_application_error(-20001, 'No data change allowed on the last day of month!'); 
END;
/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341496/oracle-trigger-for-date/23341645#23341645

Comment: Mihai, the trigger was created successfully BUT IT DOESN'T WORK! the table updates where on the last day of month. your advice doesn't work.

Comment: Art, thank you! modified the trigger as in that example and it started to work! yoohoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:new is used only in **insert** and **update** trigger

Why to use trigger at all?

```
drop table t1;
create table t1 (
col1 date,
CHECK (last_day(col1) <> col1)
);
insert into t1 values (last_day(sysdate)-1);
insert into t1 values (last_day(sysdate));
```

Also, look at a stack of exception that you are getting from trigger in a comment to this answer (everything looks normal to me).

Here is my output from your trigger:

```
SQL Error: ORA-20001: No data change allowed on the last day of month
ORA-06512: at "DBO_QBMS.t1_TR", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'myschema.t1_TR'
```

Comment: My trigger works, but, for some reason, I'm getting an error during ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.FORBID_LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH'. What can be the source of the problem?

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER forbid_last_day_of_month
 BEFORE UPDATE ON flight
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF (:new.departure = last_day(:new.departure)) THEN
 raise_application_error(-20001,'No data change allowed on the last day of month'); 
 END IF;
END;